# display the changed content in a file to web ui

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, textarea

I'm working on a display log application in Ruby

I've a script which runs in the terminal. While running in the terminal it display output in the console. I want to display it on a textarea in the web UI.

The following are the steps that I used:

1. I saved the result to a String variable and displayed the result to the textarea. But here the results will be displayed only after the command execution

In the controller and in that at present I've added 
**def test
  @test=%x(/home/test.sh)
end**

And in the view 
**%textarea{:cols => "100%", :name => "textarea", :readonly => "readonly", :rows => "25%", :style => "color: white; background-color: black"}= @test**

2. Save the result to a file and display the file, Here also the same problem as above.

Please suggest a method that I can use to display the results real time, while executing itself to see the results on the textarea in the UI.

Comment: Is streaming what you are after? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html

Comment: So you must have a controller action that is pulling this data, correct?  Couldn't you just execute the script as the first step of the controller `show` method?  something like ``construct_data_file`` or whatever your commandline script is called?

Comment: Use Ajax and refresh results at a certain interval. Or use `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`.